# Import Google Doc data into a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, import, javascript

I have a spreadsheet which has all my data for a mail merge. At present, I have simple text in a single cell to create the template for my email. It looks a little something like this:

"Hi ${Name}, we missed you in class today. Here's what you missed: ${Class Summary}. Have a great day!"

The template works fabulously, but I hate that there's no spell check in Sheets, so I'd like to either:

1. USE SCRIPTS: Draft the template in a Google Doc and use my scripts to call the Doc as my template. (The issue I've run into with this is Google's discontinuation of getByID and getByURL.)
2. USE FORMULAS: Draft the template in a Google doc and import the template into a single cell in Sheets.

Is either method possible?

Comment: Welcome. Maybe this is just me, but in the Google Sheets main menu (Tools, Spelling, Spell check). Not sure how/whether it is accessible by script, but seems to work in a blank spreadsheet that I just created.

Comment: In terms of giving you some options, have you considered doing the merge from Docs rather than Sheets?